# Adobe Flash Builder Mobile - Check Internet connection and choose view

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

Is possible to check Internet connection, than choose view according to connection/no connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following code will be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" firstView="views.TestConnectionHomeView" applicationDPI="160" creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import air.net.URLMonitor;


        private var monitor:URLMonitor;

        public function init():void{
            monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'));
            monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, announceStatus);
            monitor.start();
        }

        public function announceStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
            trace("Status change. Current status: " + monitor.available);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Please see this link [Detecting HTTP connectivity](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html)  for a more explanation.